# When trying to get user input in HTML form using .value it is not returning the live value, but instead the default

Tags: javascript, html, input

In JS and HTML I am trying to make it that when a user inputs their email address and clicks a login button the JS program will `alert()` the email address that they inputted.
Instead, all the program does is alert the default value, `value="___@gmail.com"`, and not the value that the user inputted. I read something about getting the default value vs. the new value, but it never quite explained. Is it that `.value` needs to be different?

*FYI, the snippet doesn't work*

```js
function myFunction() {
 var x = document.getElementById("emailData").value;
 alert(x)
}
document.getElementById("loginButton").onclick = myFunction;
```

```html
<ion-icon name="mail-outline"></ion-icon>
<input type="email" id="emailData" value="___@gmail.com" required>
<label for="">Email</label>

<button id="loginButton">Log in</button>
```

Comment: Should be `document.getElementById("loginButton").onclick = myFunction;`, your code sets the "onclick" property to the result of **calling** the function.

Comment: Oh thanks, that fixes one of the other problems I was having. I think I'm used to having to use `()` to call a function.

Comment: That is correct, but in this case you want a reference to the function instead of calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting the event listener via `.addEventListener()` the snippet works

```
function myFunction() {
 var x = document.getElementById("emailData").value;
 alert(x)
}

document.getElementById("loginButton").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

Comment: So why is this what is needed?

Comment: Check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick